# How to run .php in python?

Tags: php, python-3.x

I have the following `python` script `test.py`:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["php", "C:/Documents and Settings/user/My Documents/Downloads/load_data.php"])
```

the idea is to run another php script in which I make a `LOAD DATA INFILE` to a `MySQL` table, but it generates the following error:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
    File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    subprocess.call<["php","load_data.php"]>
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in call
   with Popen<*popenargs, **kwargs> as p:
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py" line 859, in __init__
   restore_signals, start_new_session>
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1114, in _execute_child startupinfo>
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

If I run the direct `load_data.php` script in a web browser, it works without any problem so it seems to me that the problem is in `python`, it is worth mentioning that I have done this correctly before but with `python 3.6`, some idea if I need it configure something or add a library.

I have `php5.3`, `apache 2.2.21`, `mysql5.5.20`, `python3.4`, I tried to put the absolute path of the `PHP` script but is the same

Regards!

Comment: Include the full path to the PHP file

Comment: still the same :/

Comment: And to the executable as well. IIRC `subprocess()` doesn't call out to the shell, it directly invokes the executable. Therefore it likely isn't searching the PATH for matching executables.

Comment: @Sammitch  subprocess.call(["C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10", "C:/Documents and Settings/user/My Documents/Downloads/load_ctb.php"])?

Comment: As it works through web,then I think use `curl yourdomain/yourphppath.php` is better choise

Answer (score 1):

For run PHP with Python, you must add the full path to the PHP executor and the full path of the file to execute.
Example :

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php5.3\\php.exe", "C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\My Documents\\Downloads\\load_data.php"])
```

Don't forget to escape the anti-slashes, Otherwise the subprocess will not work and there will be no visible error.